# generate an overly mixed vector

Tags: r

Imagine a smooth cline of colours running across an x-axis, from white on the left to red on the right. This gradient is described by `x`.

```
set.seed(444)
x <-sort(runif(10,0,1))
x
 #[1] 0.04887351 0.05602405 0.16805309 0.18510214 0.28311653 0.36549003 0.38968610 
 #    0.55943791 0.57680379 0.84906069
```

In `x` elements beside each other in the vector are more similar than those further apart in the sequence. I can mix this vector randomly with `sample(x,10)`. But if I want to shuffle `x` so that numbers beside each other (nearest neighbours) are more likely to be different than each other than those far apart, what is a good way to achieve this?

e.g. for x the correlation between an element and the average of its closest elements is explicitly:

```
neighbour <- c(x[2],mean(x[1],x[3]),mean(x[2],x[4]),mean(x[3],x[5]),
               mean(x[4],x[6]),mean(x[5],x[7]),mean(x[6],x[8]),
               mean(x[7],x[9]),mean(x[8],x[10]),x[9])
 cor(x,neighbour)
#[1] 0.9539783
```

I would like to produce shuffle `x` to produce a vector where the `cor()` is strongly negative.

Comment: Maybe you could give an example of how you want the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is not really reasonable to test every permutation and take the one with the minimal `cor` value (since the number of permutations is `10!` i.e. 3 628 800), you can try an optimization. Here is one way to do it:

```
a <- sort(runif(10,0,1))

#The function to minimize
f<-function(par,vec){
    x<-vec[par]
    neighbour <- c(x[2],mean(x[1],x[3]),mean(x[2],x[4]),mean(x[3],x[5]),
               mean(x[4],x[6]),mean(x[5],x[7]),mean(x[6],x[8]),
               mean(x[7],x[9]),mean(x[8],x[10]),x[9])
    cor(x,neighbour)
    }

# A function to generate a new permutation to test  
g<-function(par,vec){sample(par, length(par))}

res <- optim(par=seq_along(a), fn=f, gr=g, vec=a, method="SANN", 
      control=list(maxit = 30000, temp = 2000, trace = TRUE, REPORT = 500))
```

Your result is then `a[res$par]`.